# How to calculate Mean of specific values in each row of a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of size (19000x31). I am trying to calculate mean of each row. The values in each row range from 0 to 255. However, I want to calculate mean for values in between 0 and 100 only for each row, i.e., the values which are above 100 should not be considered for mean calculation. I have used DataFrame.Replace and DataFrame. Mean for doing that. But unable to get what I need. Is there any function I can use for doing that directly, else is it possible to replace the values with NaN and calculate the average. I am not getting correct replace when I tried to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

# convert from dataframe to numpy array
a = df.to_numpy()

# create mask of "interest"
mask = np.logical_and(a>=0, a<=100)

# Compute row mean
(a*mask).sum(axis=1)/mask.sum(axis=1)
```

Let's compare numpy vs pandas performances:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create fake dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 255, (19000, 31)))

def np_masked_row_mean(df, lower, upper):

    # convert from dataframe to numpy array
    a = df.to_numpy()

    # create mask of "interest"
    mask = np.logical_and(a>=lower, a<=upper)

    # Compute row mean
    return (a*mask).sum(axis=1)/mask.sum(axis=1)

%timeit df[(df >= 0) & (df < 100)].mean(axis=1)
131 ms ± 38.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np_masked_row_mean(df, 0, 100)
8.06 ms ± 385 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

which makes numpy implementation 15-16x times faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df >= 0) & (df < 100)].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide some explanation on how it works.